# Who first started parameterizing hyperbolas with hyperbolic functions?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Anyone know the history of using hyperbolic functions to parameterize the parabola?  Wolfram hasn't really helped. Anyone know where to look?

Comment: For those interested, this was [previously asked in Mathematics Stack Exchanged](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4182853/13130) (with a bit more context), which I answered there before realizing (maybe 30 minutes after I posted my answer there) that it had subsequently asked here.

Answer (score 1):

For the old version of the question, who first used the terms:

I got this at [Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics](https://jeff560.tripod.com/h.html)

> HYPERBOLIC SINE and HYPERBOLIC COSINE. Vincenzo Riccati (1707-1775) introduced hyperbolic functions in volume I of his *Opuscula ad Res Physicas et Mathematicas pertinentia* of 1757. Presumably he used these terms, since he used the notation Sh *x* and Ch *x*.

Comment: Google immediately gives: Hyperbolic functions were introduced in the 1760s independently by Vincenzo Riccati and Johann Heinrich Lambert. Riccati used Sc. and Cc. (sinus/cosinus circulare) to refer to circular functions and Sh. and Ch. (sinus/cosinus hyperbolico) to refer to hyperbolic functions. So Lambert was also involved.

Comment: https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/321922717729.pdf.bannered.pdf

Comment: I recall an old copy of Janke & Emde.  They used $\operatorname{Sin}$ and $\operatorname{Cos}$ for the trig functions, with $\frak{Sin}$ and $\frak{Cos}$ for the hyperbolic functions.